# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double' SQFlite

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I am trying to save some JSON data into a local database using SQFlite. I'm trying to save `int id, String parkingSpot, double latitude, double longitude`

All goes well when saving, however, when trying to read all the saved data, I get this exception: `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double'`

It points to this code:
`maps.forEach((map) => spots.add(ParkingSpot.fromMap(map)));`
`latitude = map[columnLatitude];`

database_helpers.dart

```
// data model class
class ParkingSpot {

  int id;
  String parkingSpot;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  ParkingSpot();

  // convenience constructor to create a ParkingSpot object
  ParkingSpot.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map[columnId];
    parkingSpot = map[columnParkingSpot];
    latitude = map[columnLatitude];
    longitude = map[columnlongitude];
  }

  // convenience method to create a Map from this ParkingSpot object
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      columnParkingSpot: parkingSpot,
      columnLatitude: latitude,
      columnlongitude:longitude
    };
    if (id != null) {
      map[columnId] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

```
class Databasehelper
...

Future<List<ParkingSpot>> queryAllParkingSpots() async {
    Database db = await database;
    List<Map> maps = await db.query(tableParkingSpots);

    if (maps.length > 0) {
      List<ParkingSpot> spots = [];
      maps.forEach((map) => spots.add(ParkingSpot.fromMap(map)));
      return spots;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

main.dart

```
  void _read() async {
    DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    final spots = await helper.queryAllParkingSpots();
    print(spots);
    if (spots != null) {
      spots.forEach((spot) {
        print('row ${spot.id}: ${spot.parkingSpot}');
      });
    }
  }

  _save(String spotName, lat, lng) async {
    if(lat != null && lng != null) {
      saved = true;
      ParkingSpot spot = ParkingSpot();
      // lat == double.parse(lat.toString());
      // lng == double.parse(lng.toString());
      spot.parkingSpot = spotName;
      spot.latitude = lat;
      spot.longitude = lng;
      DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
      int id = await helper.insert(spot);
      print('inserted row: $id');
    } else {
      print('cannot insert it');
    }
  }
```

I have tried to convert the doubles to Strings, using `lat == double.parse(lat.toString());`, but that throws the same exception.

I cannot seem to find and fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your correct in doing `double.parse`, you just need to do it in your `fromMap` constructor.

```
latitude = map[columnLatitude] is String ? double.parse(map[columnLatitude]) : map[columnLatitude];
longitude = map[columnlongitude] is String ? double.parse(map[columnlongitude]) : map[columnlongitude];
```